# PowerShell ISE: Test-Connection: No parameter was found which corresponds to the parameter name

Tags: powershell, parameters

I'm trying to write a simple script via PowerShell ISE. This is the following code ...

```
$var1 = Test-Connection -TargetName www.google.com
IF($var1 -eq "true") {
   Write-Host Connection successful
}
ELSE {
   Write-Host Connection failed
}
```

So the main issue is the

> parameter "-TargetName" is not detectable

When I try to run this script it shows the following error.
[Test-Connection: Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmJVi.png)

I don't know how to solve this problem. Why is the parameter not found?

The first line:

> Test-Connection: No parameter was found which corresponds to the
> parameter name "TargetName"

..

Comment: There is no `-TargetName` parameter on `Test-Connection`.

Comment: @Tomalak - There most certainly is (in PowerShell 7.1); see [Microsoft Docs on Test-Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-7.1). However, in earlier versions of PowerShell - like Windows Powershell 5.1 - it was called `-ComputerName` (see [Microsoft Docs on Test-Connection (for PowerShell 5.1)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-connection?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: @KekMuzaffer - Edit your question and paste the results of `$psversiontable` into it.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin PowerShell Core != PowerShell \*shrug\*

Comment: @Tomalak - Microsoft no longer makes a distinction; they _do_ distinguish between PowerShell and Windows PowerShell.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin That's... amazing. It's literally just names. :D The way I see it, there is PowerShell, and then there is that PowerShell clone that is ever so slightly incompatible for no good reason and lacks half the cmdlets. And as long as that isn't rolled out with Windows by default, it will be the odd one out.

Comment: (And yes, that's my completely subjective opinion, there is no point arguing about it. But when I see [powershell] with no special mention that it's not the default version, I'm going to assume it's about the default version.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good morning,

As mentioned in the comments, depending on your Powershell version, the parameter `-TargetName` is not available for you.

You're also checking for a `boolean` value against a string. To get it to return a `boolean` value of *True*, or *False*, supply the `-Quiet` parameter.

```
$var1 = Test-Connection -ComputerName www.google.com -Quiet -Count 1
IF($var1 -eq "true") {
   Write-Host Connection successful
}
ELSE {
   Write-Host Connection failed
}
```

As Jeff mentioned, ICMP may be off not allowing you to "*ping*" some servers which `Test-Connection` relies on. The work around is testing a specific port on that server using `Test-NetConnection`; for example: `Test-NetConnection -Port 80`.

You can also use it in a `try` and `catch` block:

```
Try{
    Test-Connection -ComputerName www.google.com -Count 1 -ErrorAction Stop | Out-Null
    "Connection Successful"
} Catch [System.Net.NetworkInformation.PingException]{
    "Connection Failed"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
Test-Connection -ComputerName www.google.com
```

Comment: Bear in mind that a lot of public sites do not respond to ping, due to pingstorms having been used as DoS attacks. Google is one such.

Comment: good point.  However, google is responding today.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you are trying to compare an object (response from command) to a string ("true") `IF($var1 -eq "true")` which would not give the expected response.

I would advise amending your script to the following:

```
$var1 = Test-Connection -TargetName www.google.com -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
IF($var1 -ne $null) {
    Write-Host Connection successful
}
ELSE {
    Write-Host Connection failed
}
```

I have added `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` as a paramater to the cmdlet so that if the website fails to respond it does not fill the console with errors.

I have also adjusted the `IF` statement to compare the variable to a null value `IF($var1 -ne $null)` as this is what will be returned if the connection fails.